Firebase - Azure AD - SAML - Forcing account choosing is not working
We are using Firebase for Auth and connected Azure AD and Firebase using below tutorial (SAML)
https://cjroeser.com/2022/12/29/tutorial-connecting-saml-oidc-oauth-2-0-providers-to-firebase-auth-azure-ad-auth0/
Now when a user signs in using AD account for the first time, user is asked to login to AD , select an account and then redirected to Firebase and then to our site. But when user logs in again, he is not shown the account picker page by AD even though select_account prompt is passed.
try {
    const samlProvider = new SAMLAuthProvider("saml.xxxx");
    samlProvider.setCustomParameters({
      prompt: "select_account",
    });
    const res = await signInWithPopup(auth, samlProvider);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("SAML Sign-In Error:", error);
  }

select_account prompt is not working.
How can I fix this?
Any help is appreciated
React is the framework
